# Positional parameters not working -can't access $1, $2 etc

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm struggling to get a handle on positional parameters. Nothing seemed to be working, then I decided to some small stuff with echo to see if it actually was working, and it wasn't. 
Could anybody explain why? 
(I'll leave out the shebang line and comments here, to get right to the point)

```
if [[ -e $1 ]]; then
    echo $#
    echo $1
fi
```

When I typed in the name of my script followed by one or more arguments, it wouldn't return anything. However, the below returned everything just as it was supposed to. I'm really at a loss.

```
if [[ -e $0 ]]; then
    echo $#
    echo $1
fi
```

Why are parameters other than $0 not recognized?

Comment: What did you specify as the parameter when using the first version? Did you specify the full path?

Comment: So what are the arguments? (see the answer below)

Comment: @coroba I was ignorantly using a file expression on an nonexistent file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash's man page:

```
CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS
    Conditional expressions are used by the [[ compound command
    and the test and [ builtin commands to test file attributes
    and perform string and arithmetic comparisons.

       -e file
              True if file exists.
```

So, if you pass a string that doesn't match an existing file as the first argument, then `[[ -e $1 ]]` will be false.

However, since `$0` usually contains the name of the shell or the script, `[[ -e $0 ]]` is more likely to be true.

(Not in all cases though. An interactive shell may be started as a login shell with a leading dash in `$0` (e.g. `-/bin/bash`), and something like `/bin/sh -c '...' foo bar` also sets `$0` to `foo`, and you can put anything you want in there.)

---

The test you probably want is `-n`:

```
   string
   -n string
          True if the length of string is non-zero.
```

So, `[[ -n $1 ]]` or just `[[ $1 ]]`.